# How to handle non-English characters extracting from MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am extracting text from a MySQL database table, collation is set to utf8_general_ci.  In PHPMyAdmin, I can see the characters correctly:

"La consiglio fermamente anche perchè ho già acquistato iWrap per il mio:"

But when I extract it myself it prints out this way:

"La consiglio fermamente anche perch� ho gi� acquistato iWrap per il mio:"

How can I make the characters print correctly?  Thanks!

Comment: Do a hex dump of a row to see if they are actually being stored correctly (ie: `SELECT HEX(column) FROM table`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Is your script utf8-encoded?
- Is the browser displaying it as utf8?
- Is your mysql connection's charset set to utf8?
- Is phpmyadmin's connection's charset set to utf8?

You can check the first in your editor.
You can check the second one in your browser (also check the http headers it receives).
You can set a mysql connection to use utf8 with a simple `SET NAMES 'utf8';` query.
Phpmyadmin's charset is displayed somewhere on it's index page.

Comment: Made these changes: '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />' in head, made a SET NAMES 'utf8' query right after my database connection.  Not fixed yet... don't know how to check if my script is utf8-encoded.  Rapid PHP 2008?

Comment: @Tim I am not familiar with that editor, maybe someone else. Check @NullUserException's comment under your opening post to make sure your data is stored as utf8.

Comment: Thanks.  I was an idiot and the SET NAMES query was not actually running.  Once it did it fixed all.

Answer (score 0):

Try using utf8_unicode instead of general.

Comment: The collation is not the issue here.

Answer (score -1):

use [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/de/function.htmlentities.php) and/or [utf8_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php)

Comment: why -1? is this bad practice? please let me know